# JSON breaks sometimes

Tags: java, json

I send json from client:

```
while (!getMessages().isEmpty() && socket.isConnected()) {
                Log.e("MQsize", getMessages().size() + "");
                Message message = messageQueue.peek();
                JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
                jsonObject.addProperty("type", MSG);
                jsonObject.addProperty("token", user.getToken());
                jsonObject.addProperty("to", message.getTo());
                jsonObject.addProperty("body", message.getMessage());
                sender.println(jsonObject.toString());
                sender.flush();
                messageQueue.poll();
}
```

as a result I got string

> {"type":"TYPE","token":"TOKEN","to":37,"body":"Hey!"}

I RECEIVE LIKE THIS:

```
    while (bytesRead != -1 && running) {
        System.out.println("bytes read: " + bytesRead);
        if (byteBuffer.position() > 2)
            {
        byteBuffer.flip();
       byte[] lineBytes = new byte[bytesRead];
       byteBuffer.get(lineBytes, 0, bytesRead);
       String line = new String(lineBytes);
       connectedSockets.add(ch);
       parseMessage(ch, line, byteBuffer);
       System.out.println("Message: " + line);
       ch.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(line.getBytes()));
       byteBuffer.clear();
           }}
```

On server side I parse this json and got the same.
BUT, sometimes, if I send multiple messages to server, it prints me correct JSON, but on parsing says "JSONException no such JsonObject("type")". While it is there such field "type". When I pring "malformed" json, it was looked like

> {"from":37,"body":"Hey!"}TOKEN","to":82,"body":"He

that's all my Json. There is no type you can see. What's going on?

My parsing func:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(clientMessage);
String type = jsonObject.getString("type");
if (type.equals(OPEN))
    open(ch, clientMessage, byteBuffer);
if (type.equals(CLOSE))
    close(ch, clientMessage, byteBuffer);
if (type.equals(MESSAGE))
    message(ch, clientMessage, byteBuffer);
```

Comment: why don't you use gson to work with JSON format? it's as easy as ABC.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code for sending and receiving the messages?

Comment: Please share the code you use to send and receive the messages